# Can I use my Chinese name and if so, how do I say it?

Tags: kanji, names, chinese

My Chinese name in Kanji is 王元劭 (Wang Yuan Shao). I've heard there are many different readings I can use for each kanji, am I allowed to use whichever reading I like? Also, apparently the character 劭 is a hyogai Kanji, which means I can't use it.

Comment: Your kanji are all included in JIS X 0208 so there is virtually no technical restriction using them in modern Japan. Did you get a response from somebody that you can't use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are supposed to call your name おう・げんしょう unless you challenge it. If you want to be called differently, go ahead and offer it. In that case, you'd use katakana like ワン・ユァンシャオ.

p.s. I'm Japanese but I haven't heard that one cannot use hyogai kanji.

Comment: 「ユァン」っていうつづり初めて見ました…。通常は「ユエン」あたりだと思うんですけどどうでしょうか。

Comment: 適当に例示しただけなんで・・・

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually see foreign names written in Newspapers etc is that Kanjis that are not hyougai are used, with the original pronunciation transliterated as furigana, and instead of the hyougai kanji, katakana is used. An example is the Go player 李世乭, where 乭 isn't used in Japanese. The way his name is usually written is thus 李｛イ｝世｛セ｝ドル

Comment: でも・・・李世ドルさんは韓国人で、OPは中国の方ですよね・・・中国人の習近平は日本語読みで「シュウキンペイ」と呼ぶのに、韓国人の朴槿恵は韓国語読みで「パククネ」って呼びますよね・・・