# Are there many ways to read kanji for names?

Tags: kanji, names, chinese

I've seen many different dictionaries and such, and many have a name section where you may put in any kanji. Because I have a Taiwanese origin, I have Chinese characters that can be used as kanji: 王元劭. Are the dictionaries correct and can I choose any reading? These readings don't seem to be kunyomi or onyomi.

[image: dictionary]

Comment: Did you check the answers to your [previous question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/46448/can-i-use-my-chinese-name-and-if-so-how-do-i-say-it)? If I understand the highest voted one correctly, you could ask to change your name's reading to 「ワン・ユァンシャオ」 or 「ワン・ユエンシャオ」. Or do you mean that you want a completely new reading that doesn't sound like your Chinese name?

Comment: I did see the answers on my previous question and I'm curious whether these readings are correct.

Comment: @ElvioWang Those readings in that dictionary are correct one for each family that has each name. But they are proper names and not your name or the readings for your name.

Answer (score 2):

Many names in Japanese that are written with kanji can have different readings. That is not to say that they DO have different readings, however.

I used to live in a place called Nogata, but when I was first given the name, I was told I was going to Nakata. The Japanese person who told me had no idea that the reading was different.

However, no one in Nogata would say that the town was Nakata.

Comment: I think the question is not about place names in Japan, but rather how to choose an appropriate reading for a Chinese name.